# Objective C: button only works if clicked twice

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My button only registers when it is clicked twice for some reason. Anyone know why?

```
- (IBAction)refreshButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    keynames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    keynums = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Firebase *resp = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://somelink"];
    [resp observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        int x = 0;
        [tabView beginUpdates];
        for (NSString* key in snapshot.value){
            [mutkeynames addObject:key];
            [mutkeynums addObject:snapshot.value[key][@"value"]];
            x++;
        }

        [tabView endUpdates];

    }];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tabView reloadData];

    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it requires 2 clicks and it's not a click once and wait for a delay? I assume you know the button was pressed by the tableview reloading? What happens if you remove the async call and reload after endUpdates

Comment: Thanks! Putting the reload inside of the Firebase download block worked.